# How to set a static int from NSTextField

Tags: objective-c

I'm having trouble setting a static int from a UI NSTextField. If I set my static value manually in the code snippet shown below:

```
int startVal = [startingTextField intValue];
static int theIndex = 1;
```

it generates no errors of course. However if I try to set the static from an int taken from the textField (as I want to) like this:

```
int startVal = [startingTextField intValue];
static int theIndex = startVal;
```

I get a surprising "Initializer element is not a compile-time constant" error on the second (static) line. What causes this and what is the correct syntax to use?

Comment: Tom - hope this will get those brain cells firing. Objective-C is great but this is a C problem, to do with initialising static variables. They are set to 0 if you do nothing, one of the few times that C does initialise a variable. Anyhow, see my answer on how to fix it. FWIW to use it in another file you'd have to declare it like so (in the other file) ```extern int theIndex;```. Hope all this helps, otherwise let me know and we can continue this in a chat.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The message explains it. If you set it equal to 1 the compiler can do so as it is known at compile time. You will have to do it differently, e.g.

```
static int theIndex = 1;
```

and then later when you know value, in some method

```
theIndex = [startingTextField intValue];
```

The problem is with the initialisation, not the assignment.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation and answer, skaak, which was a great help. I now have it working perfectly :-) On the very few occasions I've used statics before I set them directly (as shown in first code snippet), and never had to 'import' their value from the UI which caught me out. Your help is much appreciated!

Comment: Tom! Take a look at the ```dispatch_once``` snippet in Xcode which is how you normally initialise these in Objective-C, especially if they are singletons as they often are. Yours obviously is not, so I assumed you may use it to transfer info to another file thus the ```extern``` explanation bit.

Comment: ... and glad I could help ... yours in geriatrics ...

Comment: skaak. Well, at least our brains appear to be still working ... if nothing else :-)